# Issues with inputstream outofmemory errors

Tags: android, spring, bitmap, arrays, inputstream

I'm using the SpringFramework for Android to get my inputstreams.

```
    @Override
    public InputStream getImageStream(String url) {

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(template.getForObject(url, byte[].class));

    return is;

}
```

For the first few inputstreams its going ok. No Problems at all, but then, I think it tries to get a very big inputstream. So then I get the outofmemory error.

I see a lot of posts using something like the following code:

```
public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }

      byte[] byteArray= byteBuffer.toByteArray();

      return byteArray;
}
```

The idea of this code is to read the inputstream in chunks right?

But the outofmemory error I'm getting is before I can even start the readBytes method. I tried putting resets everywhere...I thought maybe I should clear the memory somewhere after readbytes or something. But I do not know how and I don't know if that is the right way?

I think I'm having the basics wrong? I'm very new to android and java... Is there a way of getting the InputStream another way? I also read something about BufferedInputStream but I just can't think up of a way to fit it in.

My goal is to store a blob of the image in the database. And my input is the imgurl via oauth.

I can also call less quality versions of the inputstream through another url. And then everything works...
But I wanted to try it with the original image url, because maybe later I want to have the ability to download an original for printing the photo.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting OutOfMemory error because you reading whole data in memory when using `ByteArrayInputStream`. Also notice that when you write in `ByteArrayOutputStream` it keeps data in memory too (it just simple wrapper for byte array). Probably you should use `FileOutputStream` instead as cache.

Comment: So I am actually doing things double? should the readbytes part be in the getimagestream method?

Comment: `template.getForObject(url, byte[].class)` should return `InputStream` instead of byte array